# Removing elements from results of glob function in TCL

Tags: tcl

I am doing :

```
glob -nocomplain *
```

as a result I get 4 files:

```
a b c d
```

how can I remove from list `b`?
I am using this func:

```
 proc lremove {args} {
     if {[llength $args] < 2} {
        puts stderr {Wrong # args: should be "lremove ?-all? list pattern"}
     }
     set list [lindex $args end-1]
     set elements [lindex $args end]
     if [string match -all [lindex $args 0]] {
        foreach element $elements {
            set list [lsearch -all -inline -not -exact $list $element]
        }
     } else {
        # Using lreplace to truncate the list saves having to calculate
        # ranges or offsets from the indexed element. The trimming is
        # necessary in cases where the first or last element is the
        # indexed element.
        foreach element $elements {
            set idx [lsearch $list $element]
            set list [string trim \
                "[lreplace $list $idx end] [lreplace $list 0 $idx]"]
        }
     }
     return $list
 }
```

however it does not working with glob results, but only with strings. please help.

Comment: How is it not working? I created a directory with 4 files: a, b, c, d and then I fired up `tclsh` entered your `lremove` definition and ran `lremove [glob -nocomplain *] b`. I got `a c d` as output. So, what's not right?

Comment: try: mkdir 1; mkdir 2; mkdir 3; touch 1/abc; touch 2/cfg; touch 3/kfk;  lremove [glob -nocomplain */*] f

Comment: And what should be removed here? None of the files are named `f`...

Comment: I want that if file consist f , so it would be removed. for example: 3/kfk.

Comment: Ohh, just use `-glob` instead `-exact` for lsearch. I assume that you want to remove files that matches `*f*` (Pass `*f*` as remove parameter). Use `\`` to format inline code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `lreplace` procedure is rather dodgy, really, what with swapping the order around, ghetto concatenation and `string trim` to try to clean up the mess. Yuck. Here's a simpler version (without support for `-all`, which you don't need for processing the output of `glob` as that's normally a list of unique elements anyway):

```
proc lremove {list args} {
    foreach toRemove $args {
        set index [lsearch -exact $list $toRemove]
        set list [lreplace $list $index $index]
    }
    return $list
}
```

Let's test it!

```
% lremove {a b c d e} b d f
a c e
```

Theoretically it could be made more efficient, but it would take a lot of work and be a PITA to debug. This version is way easier to write and is *obviously correct*. It should also be substantially faster than what you were working with, as it sticks to purely list operations.

---

The results from `glob` shouldn't be particularly special that any unusual effort be required to work with them, but there were some really nasty historic bugs that made that not always true. The latest versions of 8.4 and 8.5 (i.e., 8.4.20 and 8.5.15) don't have the bugs. Nor does any release version of 8.6 (8.6.0 or 8.6.1). If stuff is behaving mysteriously, we'll get into asking about versions and telling you to not be quite so behind the times…